# Чи потрібно виділяти комою "З повагою..."?

Tags: пунктуація, етикет

В ділових листах в кінці зустрічаємо фрази "З повагою...", "З найкращими побажаннями...". Була переконана, що після таких слів ставиться кома - ["З повагою, міський голова Львова"](http://city-adm.lviv.ua/news/government/6875-miskij-golova-lvova-zvernuvsa-do-lideriv-politichnih-sil-ukrajini). Та скориставшись ґуглопошуком виявила, що кому там ставити не потрібно.([1](https://julija-savenko.jimdo.com/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/), [2](http://omelchuk.ks.ua/uk/2018/01/18/%D1%87%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC/)) Хоча в англійські мові за аналогією пишуть - "Sincerely yours,..." І за інтонацією робимо паузу, що на письмі мало б віддзеркалитись комою. У вищезгаданих джерелах пропонують використовувати тире.

Як правильно виділяти фрази "З повагою...", "З найкращими побажаннями..." в кінці ділових листів, і чи потрібні там розділові знаки взагалі?

Answer (score 6):

З підручника [Ділова українська мова](http://pidruchniki.com/1873031738363/dokumentoznavstvo/sluzhbovi_listi#28)

> Чекаємо на Ваші пропозиції про відвідування Головного павільйону НВЦ
>   України.
>
> Режим роботи: Контактні телефони:
>
> з 10.00 до 17.30, крім суботи та неділі 251-91-40; 251-91-42
>
> З повагою,
>
> заступник генерального (підпис) Т.Г. Цимбал
>
> директора НВЦ (печатка)

[Зразки ділових листів](https://labook.com.ua/book_stilistika-dilovo-movi_672/52_-51.-zrazki-dlovih-listv) (Г. Й. Волкотруб **СТИЛІСТИКА ДІЛОВОЇ МОВИ**)

> 1. ...3 повагою
>
> заступник голови А. Толстоухов
>
> 2. ...3 повагою — Гліб Вишлінський,
>
> Директор публікацій Міжнародного центру перспективних досліджень

[Експрес-урок з О. Авраменко](https://tsn.ua/video/video-novini/ekspres-urok-ukrayinskoyi-movi-etiket-i-koma.html)

> В кінці листа при підписі слід використовувати тире, оскільки це
>   неповні речення.
>   З повагою - Віталій Кличко.
>   Щиро Ваша - Софія
>   Ротару.

[Етикет ділового листування](http://pidruchniki.com/1031020840649/dokumentoznavstvo/etiket_dilovogo_listuvannya)

> З повагою
>
> З повагою і найкращими побажаннями
>
> Зі щирою повагою (пошаною)
>
> З найщирішою до Вас повагою (пошаною)
>
> З повагою, вдячністю та побажанням успіхів
>
> Після прощальної формули ввічливості розділовий знак не ставиться, з
>   нового рядка оформлюється реквізит "Підпис".

Хоча і знайшла один приклад використання коми після словосполучення "З повагою..", але більшість джерел не радить її використовувати. Отже, варто використовувати тире або не використовувати жодних розділових знаків.

Comment: Мені здається, що ваш приклад з підручника відрізняється від інших. Можливо саме ця різниця і вимагає викоритсання коми?

Comment: @Yola якщо чесно, я трохи запуталась. Мені здається, можемо використовувати і кому, і тире, і без розділових знаків...

Comment: Дивіться, там лист і написано в два рядки, це може бути важливим.

Answer (score 5):

На сайті [Київська медіашкола](http://www.media-school.com.ua/2013/09/blog-post_27.html) подана стаття "Чи треба ставити кому після сполучення «з повагою» в ділових листах?":

> Очевидно, ці конструкції є неповними реченнями. Натомість повні речення мають таку форму: *Із подякою до вас звертається ректорат КНЕУ*.
>
> На місці пропуску слів у неповних реченнях ставлять здебільшого тире. Якщо сполучення слів з повагою, з подякою тощо вжиті безпосередньо перед прізвищем, назвою посади, назвою установи, організації, то між ними ставлять **тире**.
>
> Якщо такі звороти розміщені в одному рядку на відстані від прізвища, назви посади, назви установи, організації або в другому рядку, нижче від них, то між ними **не вживають розділових знаків**. Увічливого, дружнього тону вашому листу нададуть завершальні фрази на зразок Щиро Ваш...; Із найкращими побажаннями...; Щиро відданий Вам...; а офіційного характеру – З повагою...; Із вдячністю й повагою...; З повагою та найкращими побажаннями...

Також О. Авраменко у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://tsn.ua/video/video-novini/ekspres-urok-ukrayinskoyi-movi-etiket-i-koma.html) каже, що речення типу "з повагою Віталій Кличко" є неповними, бо можна додати "з повагою ставиться до Вас Віталій Кличко". Таким чином або жодного розділового знаку не ставимо, або ж ставимо тире. Наприклад:

> З повагою - Віталій Кличко
>
> З повагою Віталій Кличко

P. S.: Бачила ще фото, де чітко написано із прикладами, однак не можу знайти. Якщо натраплю, то обов’язково кину.